# How to seamlessly position a hidden youtube video on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, youtube

**Two examples:**

- https://chill.com/arithegreat/passive-aggressive
- https://www.simple.com

---

**It's similar to the modal dialog / light box phenomenon.** In that...

- The background darkens or blurs (but in a more localized fashion than a typical lightbox)
- The opening of the video/modal is triggered by clicking a link
- You can close the video, which, a) stops play, b) hides the video, c) brings back the content that the video replaced

**However, it provides a more seamless experience.** In that...

- The video gets positioned within a specific element on the page (instead of in relation to the some page wrapper or viewport)
- The video often replaces/hides content instead of just sitting on top of it

Here's the catch though... both of these examples use proprietary video players. That's a deal breaker in this situation. **I need it to use youtube's iframe embed code** (their new stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty robust solution. But I suck at JS so it's a total hack-job. Feel free to iterate or diverge.

**What it does decently:**

- shows/hides a youtube video "in place", at the press of a link
- some fun bg blur, etc as a proof of concept
- fluid width frame, which due to fit vids, contains fluid width video

**What it does badly:**

- the `.videoWrapper` is sized to the height of the video automatically (due to fit vids), which isn't ideal because it would be nice to be able to enlarge/shrink the container to fit the content it held before/after (instead of having to stick w/ the max height of the video)
- video does NOT stop playing when it's hidden
- anything else you notice.

**Working Example:** http://codepen.io/jonamar/pen/JAfqc

**Requires** jQuery and http://fitvidsjs.com

**HTML**

```
<section class="videoWrapper">
<!-- the <h1> and <a> get replaced -->
<h1>Watch the best video ever</h1>
<a class="control play" href="#">Play</a>
<a class="control hide" href="#">Hide</a>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5SjtrUYRYx4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
* {-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;}

.videoWrapper {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px; 
  background: #eee;
  }

iframe, .hide {display: none;}

.showVideo {background: #444;}

.showVideo h1{
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
  }

.showVideo a {color: white;}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.control').click(function () {

  $('.videoWrapper iframe').toggle();
  $('.videoWrapper .play').toggle();
  $('.videoWrapper .hide').toggle();

  var showVideo = $('.videoWrapper').hasClass('showVideo');

  if (showVideo === true) {
    $('.videoWrapper').removeClass('showVideo');
  } else {
    $('.videoWrapper').addClass('showVideo');
  }

});

$(".videoWrapper").fitVids();

});
```